# Inconsistent result with custom MarshalJSON

Tags: json, go

I have encountered some rather strange behaviour when working with custom `MarshalJSON` functions in `go`.

Consider the following setup:

```
type ISODate struct {
    time.Time
}

var nilTime = (time.Time{}).UnixNano()

func (ct *ISODate) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if ct.Time.UnixNano() == nilTime {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", ct.Time.Format("2006-01-02"))), nil
}
```

What I would then expect is that when I marshal an `ISODate` to `json` I get a date of the format `2006-01-02`. This however only happens in some of the cases.

When marshalling `ISODate`s wrapped like so:

```
var d ISODate = ISODate{Time: time.Date(9999, time.December, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999999, time.UTC)}
m1 := map[int]ISODate{1: d}
m2 := map[int][]ISODate{1: []ISODate{d}}
    
b, err := json.Marshal(m1)
b, err = json.Marshal(m2)
```

It gives the following results:

```
{"1":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z"}
{"1":["9999-12-31"]}
```

[Try it on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-FJB5uJNdou)

What I would expect is for both `ISODate`s to look like the second case.

My question is whether there is some error in my implementation or if this behaviour is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case your custom marshaller is not getting called - but instead the default reflection-based `json.Marshaler`:

https://play.golang.org/p/fGxTjKbsM5X

To fix, change your function signature to a non-pointer receiver:

```
// func (ct *ISODate) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)  { /* ... */ }
func (ct ISODate) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) { /* ... */ }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rgreJol19FO

---

***Edit***:

you can coerce the marshaler to use a pointer receiver - and also handle the `nil` case without the need for a special `nilTime` value:

```
func (ct *ISODate) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // a method can be called on a nil value
    if ct == nil {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", ct.Time.Format("2006-01-02"))), nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dy2XxS9hSYN

Comment: @abcalphabet added a pointer-receiver solution also, and leverage the `nil` value use case.